# Will clearing image cache delete images from phone?

Tags: images, cache

In my Oppo A3s, in the **settings** app, there is an option to clear image cach(approx. 900mb).

I just want to know, if it will delete the image from the device(or sd card) or not.

Thanks.

Comment: Posting duplicate questions is not okay. Use the contact button at the bottom of this page if you have lost access to your account and wants to regain the access.